# how to make toggle button in activity 2 control the view in activity 1 visiblity

Tags: android, android-studio, android-view, shared-element-transition

I have made a android studio app. recently i have added a snow effect to app.
since the winter season is over and i dont want to add this winter theme every year.
i have planned to add a toggle button to manually turn off the snow effect .

```
 togbtn.setOnCheckedChangeListener((buttonView, isChecked) -> {
        if (isChecked) {
            snowF.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        } else {
            snowF.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }

    });
```

right now, i have effect working indiviualy but i want the visibility option to work globally
any code or idea are welcome
short :
how to make a toggle control that control a visibility of a view here its snow view (github project) globally if i turn off the snow in settings it should invisible snow in entire project or app

reference images

1. https://i.stack.imgur.com/ps6RR.png
2. https://i.stack.imgur.com/9KBKl.jpg
3. https://i.stack.imgur.com/g782Q.png

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can use shared preferences to save current state and fetch this value in all activities where you need it.

You can find more detail about it here.

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences

Comment: See also https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/shared-preferences